# "directory/" is not recognized as such by os.path.isdir()

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to check if a file exists before returning it. So inside my script, I did:

```
print("***********")
print(args.src_path)
print(os.path.isdir(args.src_path))
```

But the terminal returns that:

```
(val_env) jovyan@jupyter-me:~/use-cases/UC_Scene_understanding/Code_Woodscape/scripts$ python semantic_map_generator.py --src_path ../data/instance_annotations/ --dst_path ../data/semantic_annotations --semantic_class_mapping configs/semantic_mapping_9_classes.json --instance_class_mapping scripts/mappers/class_names.json
***********
../data/instance_annotations/
False

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jovyan/use-cases/UC_Scene_understanding/Code_Woodscape/scripts/semantic_map_generator.py", line 69, in <module>
    src_path, dst_path, semantic_classes_mapping, instance_classes_mapping = parser_arguments()
  File "/home/jovyan/use-cases/_Scene_understanding/Code_Woodscape/scripts/semantic_map_generator.py", line 63, in parser_arguments
    raise Exception("Error: Check if the files or dirs in arguments exit!")
Exception: Error: Check if the files or dirs in arguments exit!
```

However, to me this `../data/instance_annotations/` is an example of dir that `os.path.isdir(args.src_path)` should return True.

Furthermore this directory exists:

```
$find
...
./scripts/semantic_map_generator.py
./scripts/polygon_generator.py
./scripts/mappers
./scripts/mappers/class_names.json
...
./scripts/box_2d_generator.py
./data
./data/semantic_annotations
./data/download.txt
```

Comment: Please show us some (reproducible) code in the meaning of an MWE. And don't use `os` for file-operations. `pathlib.Path` is recommended for that.

Comment: Your find doesn't show a directory called `../data/instance_annotations/` either.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that this error is not related to this part and `os.path.isdir()` method returns if `False` the file or directory doesn't exist, this error is related to the later lines of this code (probably somewhere in this code you open and read a file) but
for checking existence of a file or directory I recommend you to try `.exists()` method instead of `.isdir()` method.

```py
import os
os path.exists("blob/blob/blobfile.txt")
```

Reference: [**`os.path.exists(path)`** <sup>[Python-doc]</sup>](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists)